# Magento 2 CE Customer update REST API for email address update not validating the password

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api

Magento2 CE REST API for customer information update not validating the given password with actual password, it accepts everything.

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization: Bearer "customerToken"

Method: PUT <base_url>/rest/V1/customers/:customerID

Request:
{
  "customer": {
    "id": "45338",
    "email": "test230720195@yopmail.com",
    "firstname": "Updatetest",
    "lastname": "Testing",
    "websiteId": 1
  },
  "password": "qawsedrf!"
}
```

Is any other API exist to update customer information with password validation?

Comment: I don't know about enterprise edition but in community you need to create one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To reset customer password you can use the following request

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization: Bearer "authToken"

Method: PUT <base_url>/rest/V1/customers/me/password

Request:
{
  "currentPassword": "string",
  "newPassword": "string"
}
```

Note auth token here is a value you are getting with

```
/V1/integration/customer/token
```

And for the request in your question, you should use token from

```
/V1/integration/admin/token
```